# How to prevent to close parent window when it's child windows is active in WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

Working in WPF application ,Now I have a problem when I close a parent window it's get closed but the related child window is still in active.Please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: u could open ur child window with `.ShowDialog()`, then u cant close the parent window before u close the child window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that when you close the main window, you want this app to exit completely. In this case, you need to subscribe to the window `Closing` Event and do something like `Environment.Exit()` there (Just ensure that you are closing your app correctly). This method allows you to use many app windows at the same time, and still be able to close it quickly.

If it is not the case, and you just don't want the main windows to be closed before child windows - `ShowDialog()`, mentioned by Raizzen, is a good way.

If you don'w wont child windows be modal, then again, subscribe to the main window `Closing` event and check if child windows are closed already. If not, cancel closing event.

Comment: Thank you @Raizzen and Alex Butenko     .ShowDialog() worked